# Как активировать автоматическое увеличение/уменьшение текста?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая увеличивает/уменьшает текст при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку. Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу, чтобы текст увеличивался/уменьшался до тех пор, пока на кнопке зажата ЛКМ(левая кнопка мыши). Как это реализовать?

> HTML

```
<div>
    <button id="up">Кликните, чтобы увеличить размер шрифта</button>

    <button id="down">Кликните, чтобы уменьшить размер шрифта</button>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum,</h1> 
    <h2>dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2> 
    <h3>Accusantium nemo,</h3> 
    <h4>in maiores aspernatur,</h4> 
    <h5>a dignissimos corporis deserunt voluptatum suscipit ab dolorum!</h5> 
    <h6>Quibusdam, sed obcaecati.</h6> 
    <p>Laborum nisi quae labore ducimus dignissimos?</p>
</div>
```

> JS

```
let html = document.documentElement;
    up.onclick = function() {
        //при помощи JS увеличить размер шрифта html на 2px
        html.style.fontSize = parseInt(getComputedStyle(html, '').fontSize) + 2 + 'px';
    };

    down.onclick = function() {
        html.style.fontSize = parseInt(getComputedStyle(html, '').fontSize) - 2 + 'px';
    };
```

Comment: нажали кнопку, запустили таймер. сработал таймер изменили шрифт. отжали кнопку, убрали таймер

Comment: @teran спасибо, теперь понять бы, как это оформить в коде - просто я новичок в JS, не так давно начал изучать его...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

двигайтесь в этом направлении

```js
let ex = document.getElementById("ex");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let h = null;

//нажали кнопку
btn.onmousedown = function(e){
   //запстили таймер
   h = setInterval(function(){
          //изменили шрифт
          ex.value = (+ex.value || 0) + 1;
      }, 50);
};
// отжали кнопку
btn.onmouseup = function(){
    //убрали таймер
    clearInterval(h);
}
```

```html
<input id="ex"/>
<button id="btn">&plus;</button>
```

отпустить мышь можно и вне кнопки, поэтому данное поведение тоже следует обработать соответствующим образом

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов да, тоже заметил, запустив код. И как это можно исправить?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов я смотрю, вы невероятно внимательно читаете прежде чем писать

Comment: @IcEWaRRiOr `mouseleave` обработать, очевидно

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов тогда уточните задачу с учетом данного нюанса и не придумывайте различного рода ерунду

Comment: @OliverPatterson тоже адепт того, чтобы текст ответа до конца не читать?